# Python: Making a GUI in nokia phone

Tags: python, mobile-phones

I am writing one of the Mobile monitoring program in my phone which I almost finished it. My program has a pedometer which counts human's steps in a real time manner. My question is that I am now writing GUI for phone which will show let's say some picture after they accomplish 1000 steps(like an award) and so on. I am just new to python and does not really know anything about GUI in python. My phone is Nokia N79. My question is that where can I get the information about GUI in python in N79 phones something like examples and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which phone model and OS are we talking about? Is it running Android?

I believe pre-Android Nokia phones used Qt GUI framework

Python has Qt wrappers, look into PyQt4 for all your UI needs.

Comment: Do you know how to install Pyqt4 in Nokia N79 phone? if so, how to?